# Averaging From Measure

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm new in Power BI and I'm trying to understand some functions.

I tried 2 ways:

1 - Explicitying having the calculation in the AVERAGEX function
Avg X = AVERAGEX(Products,
Products[Amount]*Products[Discount])

2 - I tried to simplify the above by calculating the Products[Amount]*Products[Discount] in a measure first and then use it in the AVERAGEX
Avg = AVERAGEX(Products,
[Sumx])

However, I'm getting 2 different values for the last row in my table

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you give the definition of the `[Sumx]` measure? `Products[Amount]*Products[Discount]` isn't a valid measure definition (or is `[Sumx]` actually a calculated column, rather than a measure?).

Comment: [sumx] measure is SUMX(Products,Products[Amount]*Products[Discount])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the presence of duplicate rows in the table being iterated by `AVERAGEX`.

`AVERAGEX(Products, [Sumx])` will evaluate `[Sumx]` once for each row of `Products`, each time with a row-context corresponding to the row being visited by the iteration.

Both the first and second copy of the `{("Red", 50, TRUE(), 2)}` row will be visited; and set as the current row-context for the iteration step.

In each iteration step, `[Sumx]` will transform this row-context into a filter context (due to the implicit context-transition that measures apply), and will get the filter context `("Red", 50, TRUE(), 2)`. This filter context matches two rows of `Products`, so the inner `SUMX(Products,Products[Amount]*Products[Discount])` will iterate two rows.

The end result is that the `AVERAGEX(Products, [Sumx])` computes the following wrong value:

```
(
    2000*2
   +(50*2+50*2) //Both `{("Red", 50, TRUE(), 2)}` rows included in filter context of SUMX
   +(50*2+50*2) //Both `{("Red", 50, TRUE(), 2)}` rows included in filter context of SUMX again.
)
/3 //3 rows in Products (when Color="Red")
```

`AVERAGEX(Products, Products[Amount]*Products[Discount])` does not apply a context transition to the row context and iterate over the rows in this new filter context, so `Products[Amount]*Products[Discount]` evaluates to the correct value for the currently iterated row of `Products`.

Comment: Thank you Mankarse. This is a mind-bending for someone who is learning Dax. I guess I need to look further into the concept of context transition. So, in this iterative functions, is it better to avoid using a measure that is already evaluating at row level?

Comment: Yes; or you could avoid the problem by adding a column that has unique values for each row to the`Products` table (for example, a surrogate key unique column).